# Reserving space in beamer overlays

Tags: beamer, overlays

I use the beamer package. I want to achieve the following. Assume I have a slide of the following form (two elements):

XXX

YYY

XXX should be shown on all slides and **always at the same position**! YYY should be =A on the 2nd slide and =B on the 3rd slide. The problem with the existing overlay specifications is that the position of XXX depends on how much space is used by YYY. And this is different for YYY=A (2nd slide) and for YYY=B (3rd slide).

Comment: If you do not want horizontally centered text, you can use the option top (`[t]`) for the frame, which solves the problem.

Or you could use `\phantom`.

Comment: @percusse I guess you are right. And `overlayarea` works fine. `overprint` is not very robust. Also I found http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68150/16865 I wonder whether the problem is clearer from my own question. But feel free to delete my question.